# Laravel Websocket works in Firefox, not in Edge

Tags: laravel, websocket

I have installed a laravel application on a public webserver.

Apache has been configured with a Let's Encrypt certificate with certbot and the website is available in https.

Using the mydomain.it/laravel-websockets link I checked that everything is working.
Using firefox the socket connects, but using Edge it does not

I need to use websockets so I configured as follows:

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
     wsHost: window.location.hostname,
     wsPort: 6000,
     wssPort: 6001,
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     forceTLS: true,
     encrypted: true,
     enabledTransports: ['wss']
 });
```

broadcasting.php

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => 'mydomain.it',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

websockets.php

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
            'encrypted' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

.env

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=123456
PUSHER_APP_KEY=myappkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=mysecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.it/fullchain.pem
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.it/privkey.pem
```

Comment: please check if javascript is enabled on edge and if edge does not block anything related to echo, you can see the console in your browser dev tools  if there are any errors related to echo

Comment: No errors found. In Network tab the request just terminate